# Curl Error in HTTP2 framing layer when trying to install Jenkins plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins, curl

I am trying to create a custom Jenkins docker image. For that I need to install certain plugins in Jenkins. I am doing so by adding the below lines to the Dockerfile

```
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/

ENV CURL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=60
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

My plugins.txt looks like this -

```
configuration-as-code
```

I had more plugins in the list but seems like I am unable to install even if there is only one.

The full error message that I receive is -

```
Creating initial locks...
Analyzing war /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war...
Registering preinstalled plugins...
Using version-specific update center: https://updates.jenkins.io/2.235...
Downloading plugins...
Downloading plugin: configuration-as-code from https://updates.jenkins.io/2.235/latest/configuration-as-code.hpi
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
15:34:43 Failure (16) Retrying in 1 seconds...
 > configuration-as-code depends on snakeyaml-api:1.26.3
Downloading plugin: snakeyaml-api from https://updates.jenkins.io/2.235/latest/snakeyaml-api.hpi
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
15:35:39 Failure (16) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
15:35:52 Failure (16) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
15:36:05 Failure (16) Retrying in 1 seconds...
15:36:06 Failed in the last attempt (curl -sSfL --connect-timeout 60 --retry 3 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 https://updates.jenkins.io/2.235/latest/snakeyaml-api.hpi -o /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/snakeyaml-api.jpi)
Downloading plugin: snakeyaml-api-plugin from https://updates.jenkins.io/2.235/latest/snakeyaml-api-plugin.hpi
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
15:36:08 Failure (22) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
15:36:11 Failure (22) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
15:36:14 Failure (22) Retrying in 1 seconds...
15:36:15 Failed in the last attempt (curl -sSfL --connect-timeout 60 --retry 3 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 https://updates.jenkins.io/2.235/latest/snakeyaml-api-plugin.hpi -o /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/snakeyaml-api-plugin.jpi)
Failed to download plugin: snakeyaml-api or snakeyaml-api-plugin

WAR bundled plugins:


Installed plugins:
configuration-as-code:1.43
snakeyaml-api:1.26.4
Some plugins failed to download! Not downloaded: snakeyaml-api
The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Curl tries to download `snakeyaml-api-plugin` when `snakeyaml-api` fails. The latter is not being downloaded due to the error `curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer`

For multiple plugins, I get the HTTP2 framing layer error multiple times. Many a times, the installation gets stuck at a point without any progress

You can look into the shell script `install-plugins.sh` [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh)

Tested on Windows 10 as well as MacOS Mojave
Docker version -  19.03.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If HTTP/2 is not working try forcing HTTP 1.1:

```
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/

ENV CURL_OPTIONS -sSfL --http1.1
ENV CURL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT 60
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```